# How to dispose the push notification when you click in this?

Tags: android, notifications, push

Hello I have a Client and Server, I can send push and get this, it works well, but i don't have idea to dispose/disappear the notification in the panel of this.

Anyone have idea for it?

Thanks

Comment: I think you might be looking for [Notification.cancel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#cancel(int))

Comment: Maybe, this is used to cancel the notification show in the panel, really?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `NotificationCompat` and when you use it, you have an option to `setAutoCancel()`
You can use the below example:

```
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder
    .setContentIntent(intent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
    .setContentTitle(Html.fromHtml(title))
    .setNumber(number)
    .setContentText(Html.fromHtml(messages[0]))
    .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

When you do that, the clicked notification will automatically be erased.